# Content ID e Politicas de uso com Youtube API

Tags: c#, .net, youtube-api

Estou tentando subir os meus vídeos no Youtube, com Política de uso e Content Id Matching habilitados. O meu projeto está em .NET com a biblioteca  Youtube API v3, mas a biblioteca só permite a implementação abaixo que também não está funcionando.

```
video.MonetizationDetails = new VideoMonetizationDetails { Access = new AccessPolicy { Allowed = true } };
```

Gostaria de ver como eu poderia configurar com .NET as informações abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Considere melhorar e ampliar a pergunta para encontrarmos uma melhor solução em conjunto.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18800665/how-to-enable-monetization-for-videos-uploaded-with-youtube-data-api-v3